# let variable names with sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Is there a way to add a sequence to the let variable name?  Sort of like this:

```
5.times do |n|
    let (:"item_'#{n}'") { FactoryGirl.create(:item, name: "Item-'#{n}'") }
end
```

Then a test like this could work:

```
5.times do |n|
    it { should have_link("Item-'#{n}'", href: item_path("item_'#{n}'") }
end
```

It'll lead to a test for proper sorting, but just trying to understand the basics.

Edit:
There was a typo, I removed the single quotes and the let call seems to be working

```
let! (:"item_#{n}") { FactoryGirl.create(:item, name: "Item-#{n}") }
```

The test passes for a single case if I use:

```
it { should have_link("Item-0", href: item_path(item_0)
```

But not for the sequence if I use:

```
it { should have_link("Item-#{n}", href: item_path("item_#{n}")
```

I have verified the problem is in the href path. How do you interpolate item_n when the used in a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an answer to another question, I found out how to get the result of a ruby variable from a string, using `send`.  Also, I do like Erez's answer because I would like to use let variables because of the lazy evaluation.  Here is what I got working:

```
describe "test" do
  5.times do |n|
    # needs to be instantiated before visiting page
    let! (:"item_#{n}") { FactoryGirl.create(:item, name: "item-#{n}") }
  end

  describe "subject" do
    before { visit items_path }

    5.times do |n|
      it { should have_link("item-#{n}", href: item_path(send("item_#{n}"))) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because in `it { should have_link("Item-#{n}", href: item_path("item_#{n}")` the href value is not a string but a ruby variable.

What I would do in your case is:

```
before do
  @items = []
  5.times do |n|
    @items << FactoryGirl.create(:item, name: "Item-#{n}")
  end
end
```

And in the spec itself:

```
@items.each do |item|
  it { should have_link(item.name, href: item_path(item)) }
end
```

Comment: So I guess the answer is it is possible, but not worth it.  Thanks for explaining the string vs. ruby variable part.  That makes sense.  I think you need to remove the single quotes from `"Item-'#{n}'"`.  That wasn't working for me, earlier.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work.  I get exception: `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass>`. @items is nil. However, `Item.all.each` does work for my setup.